# Time / Forecasting Series with Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm looking for such a simple example of Forecast, **time series** with Machine Learning Azure Studio. I am trying to use this example:

[airlines dataset](https://github.com/log0ymxm/weka-timeseriesforecasting/blob/master/sample-data/airline.arff)

But all the examples I've looked for are so complex, can anyone give me a simple example to try to understand how to work with time series in Azure?

I would like to get a **simple example where I can see graphs and results like this in WEKA:**

[Example of results in WEKA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U09b.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Build more accurate forecasts with automated machine learning.Please follow the below documents for time series forecasting with Auto ML.
Learn more : https://aka.ms/automatedmldocs, Notebook Samples : https://aka.ms/automatedmlsamples​, Blog Post : https://aka.ms/automl-forecast​.

[image]